# How to reduce the file size after executing a cloth simulation?

Tags: cloth-simulation, cache

I have a cloth simulation and animated/baked it. My file size is now 65 MB. I understand that.

Now i want to delete my bake and cache so i tried to tap on "delete all bakes" and i hoped, if i save my file now, it would become smaller. But it won't became smaller.

My research to this was unsuccessful.

What did i make wrong? How do i really delete my bake and cache?

** UPDATE **

Ok, i have several objects with cloth modifier.

If i do this for EACH object:

1. press delete all bake
2. change 1 single property of cloth

...do this for my 12 objects

save...it reduces my file size.

If anyone has a quicker solution, please write an answer.

Comment: Some Blender users reported that in order to free the cache, they needed to "Delete all bakes" save the file, close it, open it again, save again, close again and after this second close, the file shrank back to normal

Comment: @Emir: Thanks for the proposal - unfortunately this does not work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i now build a python solution. But i will gratefully delete this answer, if someone has an easier solution.

So if you have multiple cloth objects, this python script can help:

```
import bpy


bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake_all()

for eachObject in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    for eachModifier in eachObject.modifiers:
        if eachModifier.type == "CLOTH":
            oldDamping = eachModifier.settings.bending_damping
            if eachModifier.settings.bending_damping != 0.123456:
                eachModifier.settings.bending_damping = 0.123456
            else:
                eachModifier.settings.bending_damping = 0.234
            eachModifier.settings.bending_damping = oldDamping
```

It looks like the cache is only deleted if you change one setting of your cloth modifier. So this is what this script does. I tried this out and it worked for me.

Comment: as long as you've already accessed the old damping, you can guarantee that the new value is different by using `eachModifier.settings.bending_damping = oldDamping + .001` or some such similar equation.  That will only fail if damping is clamped and the old value is closer than .001 to the max.  You could test for this, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I think it is already overkill to add 0.01. and I think the probability that someone uses the max value is much higher than using my specific value. But you can downvote my answer because of that - I don’t care.

Comment: So subtract instead.  I'm not going to downvote your answer, but if I did it would be because it's a hack that doesn't solve your problem, not because of what kind of hack it is.  Have a nice day.

Comment: subtract isn't better...it's the same problem as add.

Comment: Then pick a property that doesn't have a Blender max/min.  Now the probably of collision with the original value is 0.  By the way, I should have checked earlier.  damping doesn't have a max, so there's no problem adding to it.

Comment: every value in the computer world has a max/min....

Comment: well, it's a hack either way.  All you have to do to break it is install a version of Blender that doesn't have the setting you picked.

Comment: yeah...and you write always solutions for every blender version!? LOL sorry, but this discussion is already ridiculous....i won't answer to you anymore....my time is to precious for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131438/discussion-between-marty-fouts-and-chris).